# Size of memory allocated by new[]

Tags: c++, stl, windbg

I'm investigating a crash, and I have the stack trace below

```
...
12 4292e2c4 73148e89 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
13 4292e2fc 73150e7c MSVCR80!_CxxThrowException+0x46 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\throw.cpp @ 161]
14 4292e318 386f21ba MSVCR80!operator new+0x69 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\new.cpp @ 63]
15 4292e32c 386f1f39 StatEngineProxy!std::allocator<myClass>::allocate+0x1a [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xmemory @ 146]
16 4292e384 386ef7e8 myModule!std::vector<myClass,std::allocator<myClass> >::_Insert_n+0xf9 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector @ 1138]
17 4292e3b0 386ec20f myModule!std::vector<myClass,std::allocator<myClass> >::insert+0x88 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector @ 855]
18 4292e3dc 3872bb17 myModule!std::vector<myClass,std::allocator<myClass> >::push_back+0xaf [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector @ 800]
....
```

cause is simple: `bad_alloc`. The question is how can I find how much memory stl was trying to alloc.

Comment: From the stack trace, or from a system you can debug? Can't you set the debugger to stop on exceptions thrown?

Comment: from a system I can debug or a crash dump. I cannot reproduce the crash easily.

Comment: Doesn't your debugger allow you to insepect frame 14 and look at what was passed to operator new?

Comment: If the exception is `bad_alloc` it means `operator new` could not satisfy an allocation request either because no physical memory is left or because of memory fragmentation. You'll not likely get any additional info from any special debugging techniques either. Since the exception happens in `vector::push_back`, a call to `vector::reserve` earlier will probably fix the issue in both cases (less fragmentation, less total intermediate memory used, and as a bonus: less copying).

Comment: but operator new does not receive a parameter with the size that need to allocate ?

Comment: I suppose the question is "where is the problem", try valgrind: http://valgrind.org/

Comment: Operator new indeed receives a parameter, which you can log if you overload it, if that is what you want. But `operator new` is not the cause of the problem -- incorrect use of `std::vector` is.

Comment: I don't want to fix new :) i'm just trying to find out how much memory the vector is trying to use. But post-mortem analysis, no new logs.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You get the sources for the CRT. (Probably in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\new.cpp`). Therefore, you can view the source and variables for frame 14

You'll find that line 58 looks like `void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)`. That argument `size` is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Add `try...catch` to all your new[]'s in that class, and then set detailed debugging information inside the `catch` clause.

Comment: how that ? the new[] is called from the std::vector

Comment: Identify the points of your source code in which the std::vector tries to grow, and then surround them by try...catch clauses.

Answer (score 2):

You could give STL a custom allocator, so all its memory claims go through the functions you provide.

There's an example here:
http://www.sjbrown.co.uk/2004/05/01/pooled-allocators-for-the-stl/

Comment: That may improve general performance, but I'm willing to bet it does not solve the above problem. The custom allocator will not be able to change the fact that `vector::push_back` needs to reallocate regularly while retaining a copy, which is only freed afterwards. This leaves the allocator with "mip map sized" smaller free memory chunks afterwards, which are useless for future allocations (too small both individually and in sum). The solution is really to `reserve` early, so `vector` _does not need to_ reallocate.

Comment: It does solve the question asked, which is: how many bytes were requested?